How can I apply multiple tolerations with dynamic values in kubernetes helm values.yaml?
I apologize; I'm new to Kubernetes and yaml configuration and would like to seek help to achieve my goal related to Kubernetes spec. I want to add the following as a patch on my pixie values.yaml:

nodeSelector which has a value of pixie: allowed

Two toleration keys in which values will be obtained from a for-loop.
pixie-chart:
 enabled: ${pixieChart_enabled}
 deployKey: ${pixieChart_deployKey}
 clusterName: ${pixieChart_clusterName}
 pemMemoryLimit: ${pixieChart_memLimit}
 patches:
  vizier-pem: '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": { "nodeSelector": {"pixie": "allowed" }}}}}'
 %{for tolerationKey in tolerationKeys}
  vizier-pem: '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": { "tolerations": [{"key":"${tolerationKey}","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoSchedule"}] }}}}' 
 %{endfor}



Whenever I apply the code above and execute the command helm get values I only get one patch line:
pixie-chart:
clusterName: cluster-k8s
deployKey: xxx
enabled: true
patches:
 vizier-pem: '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": { "tolerations": [{"key":"toleration1","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoSchedule"}]
  }}}}'
pemMemoryLimit: 1Gi

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Please show us a minimal, reproducible example - as it is, it's difficult to understand where the problem is.

It's also hard to say anything about what the chart might do with a given set of values.  When you [edit] the question, please make sure to include the actual template code that generates the corresponding Deployment manifest.

You can't have multiple keys in a YAML dictionary with the same name. You're attempting to create multiple vizier-pem keys. That won't work.
